# Forward Declaration undefined class error windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio, forward-declaration

**foo.h:**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <some_wrapper.h>

namespace b
{
  class foo;
} // b

namespace a
{
  class foo
  {
  private:
    some_wrapper<b::foo> m_foo;
  };
}



#endif // FOO_H
```

**impl_foo.h:**

```
#ifndef IMPL_FOO_H
#define IMPL_FOO_H

#include <vector>
#include <foo.h>

namespace b
{
  class foo
  {
    foo()
    {

    }

  private:
    std::vector<char> m_foos;
  };
}
#endif // IMPL_FOO_H
```

**some_wrapper.h:**

```
#ifndef SOME_WRAPPER_H
#define SOME_WRAPPER_H

#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>


template<class foo, bool = std::is_copy_constructible<foo>::value>
class some_wrapper
{
  template<class... Args>
  some_wrapper(Args&&... args)
    :
      m_foo(new foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {
    static_assert(!std::is_array<foo>::value,
        "some_wrapper does not do arrays.");
  }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<foo, void(*)(foo*)> m_foo;
};



#endif // SOME_WRAPPER_H
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <impl_foo.h>    
#include <foo.h>

// didn't fill in this file further as the needed errors on windows appeared without anything further
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(forward_dec_test_lib LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_library(forward_dec_test_lib STATIC
  foo.h
  impl_foo.h
  some_wrapper.h
  foo.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(forward_dec_test_lib PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)

target_compile_definitions(forward_dec_test_lib PRIVATE FORWARD_DEC_TEST_LIB_LIBRARY)
```

The structure of this code works on the `linux` side with `gcc` and `c++ 11`. `b::foo` would be stored in it's own separate header file. Both files have header guards. But when utilized in the private space of a::foo a undefined class error is given when attempting to build with Visual Studio. This error is not seen when built on the Linux side. I'm having trouble finding documentation on why the MSVC compiler would be handing forward declarations differently. CMake is utilized for this project.

In the actual code, if the private variable in `foo.h` is moved inside of a function that utilizes it, inside of the `foo.cpp` then the issues appear to disappear, not undefined class error.

**C2139 error message:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2139   'b::foo': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_constructible'    C:\forward_dec_test_lib\out\build\x64-Debug\forward_dec_test_lib    C:\forward_dec_test_lib\some_wrapper.h  8
```

**C2976 error message**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2976   'some_wrapper': too few template arguments  C:\forward_dec_test_lib\out\build\x64-Debug\forward_dec_test_lib    C:\forward_dec_test_lib\foo.h   16
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre]. A definition for `some_wrapper` is missing, and the full error text from the compiler (not just the number).

Comment: What is `some_wrapper`? Can you try to edit enough detail into this to make it a minimal reproducible example, because right now it won't compile for the obvious reason that `some_wrapper` is not a thing, which does nothing to shed light on the difference between gcc and MSVC.

Comment: 1) What is "Private:"? 2) Missing semicolumn ; after the class definition.

Comment: Your template parameter `bool = std::is_copy_constructible<foo>::value` probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.  It's either going to be `true` or `false`, but it's unnamed and therefore unused.

Comment: @DrewDormann there is further code that deals with that in what this example is based off of. It's not essential to the issue though, because the compiler is receiving an issue when trying to created the object with `some_wrapper` in the header. Forgot to add this to the overall question, and will do so after this, but if I move the declaration of the `some_wrapper` object into the `.cpp` inside of a function that actually utilizes the private variable in the code the example is based off of these errors seem to disappear.

Comment: From what I can tell from the example, I kind of agree with MSVC: when parsing the foo.h file, it needs to instantiate some_wrapper with your default argument of `std::is_copy_constructible<b::foo>::value` and at that time `b::foo` is an incomplete type, so an error. Probably if you reverse the order of includes in the cpp file then it'll work. Also, for the MVC example here it's best not to name everything `foo`.

Comment: @MicroVirus, that's on me I didn't put those headers in that order which they should have been. But the problem still occurs regardless of order on the windows end, but not on the linux end. I'm having difficulting figuring out how/why MSVC handles this differently then the gcc compiler on the linux side. That's what this seems to be indicating to me.